# Firebase methods error - Xcode Swift -

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, debugging

Hi guys I have a very weird issue: My app is building and running fine but since this morning is giving me some error: when I went to check what's the problem, I found out that apparently, I have a ViewController that is not recognising any Firebase methods such as Auth.auth() or Database.datatabase() etc...
I already checked if I wrote "import Firebase" and that's done. I updated the pods but nothing changes, The app is running despite 7 red errors .-.
Someone can help me understand what's wrong? Thanks!

[List of errors in the debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c83FY.png)

[one of the errors in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OPSw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved: I changed the APP name on my Firebase Database but I forgot to update it on xCode... Updating the name of the APP on Xcode solved the problem :D